# Features that a "basic" Torrent client should use

Tags: gui-design, features

I am not exactly sure that this is the right place to ask this question, but anyways, I am an eighth grader, looking to rewrite the rTorrent GUI (type thingy) nTorrent (hosted at http://code.google.com/p/ntorrent/).  I have done basic research, looking into famous and widely-used torrent clients for the best features from each.  I am not sure, as I haven't frequently used torrent-ing in the past, what features are key.  What is important to show the user?

Comment: Yeah. This isn't the right place for such questions. You need to talk to Torrent users about their expectations.

Comment: As per the FAQ this isn't really a question we can answer; we prefer problems that are narrowly defined and/or objectively answerable. Quora could be a better resource if you just want a survey of "what's important in a Torrent client".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good on you taken on a project like this only in eighth grade! Anyways have a look at Transmission for Mac it as a few really usefull features that most torrent users would find quite handy:

1. Name of Torrent
2. Progress Bar of Download, with Progress of Upload
3. Download and Upload Speed
4. Seeders and Lechers
5. Icon signifying type of torrent (e.g., movie, folder, mp3)
6. Tons of extras for power-user but the above are musts for a good UX using a torrent program

Now if you can combine the mathematics of what makes a good torrent (good download and many seeders) and show a health indicator of the torrent as well then you are in business!

Transmission also has many other unique features like: watching folders for new torrents and adding them automatically to your download queue and the ability to select only specific files in the torrent.

Check it out here: http://www.transmissionbt.com/images/screenshots/Mac-Large.png from http://www.transmissionbt.com/

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is VERY helpful.  And by the way, if you know Java (or any other language, I guess) and would like to help, email the 'owner' of the page on which it is hosted.